# fix virtual consols fires with A:T+Fx (without CTRL)

Tags: gnome, virtual-console

When I press ALT+any Fx (x in range of 1..7) keys fresh install Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 switches virtual console, and when I return to GUI it executes repetive ALT+Fn command. For example if I press Alt+F4 it switches console and after I return closed the window. Please note the in keyboard shortcuts app virtual consoles switch is set to CTRL+ALT+Fx.

Something is really wrong as it should switch virtual console ONLY on CTRL+ALT+Fx.

Please help me to stop it calling virtual consoles action without CTRL.

Thanks in advance. (if any logs need, please let me know the command and I'll post it here)